# How to load a text file and plot multiple columns in a single figure

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a text file with 5 columns. The 1st one is the X-axis (1,2,3,4), and the rest of the columns are for the y-axis. I want to plot them in one graph.

```
1 0 0 0 0
2 7 14 2.53381 0.0691848
3 6 16 2.61242 0.0507856
4 6 17 2.65154 0.040285
```

I am trying this code for a single `y` value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

file_name = input("Enter the file name:")

x, y = np.loadtxt(file_name, delimiter=',', unpack=True)
plt.plot(x,y, label='Loaded from file!')

plt.xlabel('Action')
plt.ylabel('Rate')
plt.title('Plot of Rate')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

How can multiple `y` values be extracted, and plotted?

Answer (score 2):

Use `*y` to store all columns data(after x column) in y variable.
Use `delimite=' '` if your data is space-separated.

So just do this correction while loading file and leave other code as it is):
`x, *y = np.loadtxt(file_name, delimiter=',', unpack=True)`

which results:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check the snippet
[image: lines]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

df = pd.read_csv('samp.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
df.columns = ["x", "y1", "y2", "y3","y4"]
print(df)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df['x'],df['y1'], label='Line1')
ax.plot(df['x'],df['y2'], label='Line2')
ax.plot(df['x'],df['y3'], label='Line3')
ax.plot(df['x'],df['y4'], label='Line4')
tick_spacing = 1
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(tick_spacing))
plt.xlabel('Action')
plt.ylabel('Rate')
plt.title('Plot of Rate')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

- The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63886440) from [Girish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14108734/girish-dattatray-hegde) fixes the code in the OP, but this answer represents the least amount of code to produce the desired output.
- Use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to read in the file, and set column 0 as the index

  - Use `sep='\\s+'` based on the sample shown, but use the appropriate separator, if it's something other than what is in the OP.
  - Based on the sample, use `header=None`, but change it as needed for the file.
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) to plot the dataframe in 1 line.
- Additionally, the benefit of using `pandas` is the data can now be easily analyzed.  Try `df.describe()` to get column-wise statistics.

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the file
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\\s+', header=None, index_col=0)

# add column names if desired; the list must have as many values as there are columns
df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

# plot the data
df.plot(figsize=(7, 4), xlabel='Action', ylabel='Rate', title='Plot of Rate')
```

[image]

- Summary Statistics of Data

```py
df.describe()

             a       b        c        d
count  4.00000   4.000  4.00000  4.00000
mean   4.75000  11.750  1.94944  0.04006
std    3.20156   7.932  1.30055  0.02926
min    0.00000   0.000  0.00000  0.00000
25%    4.50000  10.500  1.90036  0.03021
50%    6.00000  15.000  2.57312  0.04554
75%    6.25000  16.250  2.62220  0.05539
max    7.00000  17.000  2.65154  0.06918
```

Comment: How can I plot columns in separate plots?

Comment: @AlfredoCapobianchi use `subplots=True`

Answer (score 0):

So first I loaded the data into 4 variables, one of them is x and three of them are y1, y2, y3 and then I just used the method `'plot'` three times in order to create thre different graphs

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

file_name = input("Enter the file name:")
data = np.loadtxt(file_name, delimiter=',', unpack=True)

x = data[0]
y1 = data[1] # the first graph
y2 = data[2] # the second graph
y3 = data[3] # the third graph
y4 = data[4] # the fourth graph

plt.plot(x,y1, label='y1')
plt.plot(x,y2, label='y2')
plt.plot(x,y3, label='y3')
plt.plot(x,y4, label='y3')
plt.xlabel('Action')
plt.ylabel('Rate')
plt.title('Plot of Rate')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]